# OpenVPN ERROR: could not insert 'tun': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Tags: debian, openvpn, kernel

I'm trying to configure OpenVPN on my Debian 7 VPN but I'm getting the following error `ERROR: could not insert 'tun': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

I tried the suggestions in the comments here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/modprobe-tun-error-could-not-insert-tun-unknown-symbol-in-module

When I do `apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)` it says it's already installed, also tried rebooting.

Someone also suggested upgrading to the latest kernel, I'm now on Debian 7.0 x64 vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.63-2+deb7u1) but the problem persists.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Silly question, you have rebooted since you last updated your kernel right?  Is that your post in the thread you linked to?  Do you see the same output in dmesg?

Comment: @Zoredache Yeah I did, thought it would do it automatically but apparently not so I did it manually. My dmesg is filled with these : `[ 3300.981814] tun: Unknown symbol ipv6_proxy_select_ident (err 0)`

Comment: @Zoredache I don't have a ipv6 address by the way. My VPS is hosted at DigitalOcean with an ipv4 address

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767836 It appears like you must take some steps on Digital Oceans when updating a kernel.

Comment: @Zoredache Stumbled upon it. I changed my kernel in the DO control panel but I'll try a different version.

Comment: @Zoredache Okay so I tried Debian 7.0 x64 vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 (3.2.60-1+deb7u3) which seems to work for most people with similar problems but I'm getting the same errors.